# Find the total number of points for each D, if there is no D in P, then points should be 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find the total number of points for each D. 
If there is no instance of D in P, then the points should return as 0. 
My tables are:

```
P 
code (referencing D.id), c_code (referencing C.id)

D
id, name

C
id
name
points
```

My query is:

```
SELECT D.id, SUM(C.points)
FROM D JOIN P ON D.id=P.code JOIN C ON P.c_code=C.id
GROUP BY D.id
HAVING CASE WHEN D.id NOT IN (SELECT *
                               FROM P p1
                               WHERE p1.code=D.id) THEN '0' end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need Outer Joins to get non-matching rows plus `coalesce` to return zero instead of NULL:

```
SELECT D.id, coalesce(SUM(C.points), 0)
FROM D LEFT JOIN P ON D.id=P.code
LEFT JOIN C ON P.c_code=C.id
GROUP BY D.id
```

Comment: I think the `SUM()` function ignores null values. It should naturally return zero when no value is added. No need for `COALESCE()`.

Comment: Is there an option not to use left join?

Comment: @1mpe7us: No, you need Outer Joins. Well, you *could* write a Correlated Scalar Subquery instead, but effectively it's an Outer Join, too. Btw, if you don't need additional columns from `D` (and your data is consistent) you can simply remove the 1st join and switch to `SELECT P.code` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use outer joins, as in:

```
select
    d.id, sum(c.points)
  from d
  left join p on p.code = d.id
  left join c on c.id = p.c_code
  group by d.id
```